# Custom Asp.net Identity for custom database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebApi for the first time and I want to implement token authentication for my existing users stored in the database, but I have been unable to find any good solutions to do this. I already referred to many solutions found on Google, but I have not been able to understand what mistake I am making when I implement them.

Please, if someone could give any source sample, that would be a great help.

Comment: You've mentioned that you found solutions on Google. Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42610229/edit) your question and link to which solutions you tried and explain why they didn't actually work for your case?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using this approach to generating tokens [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/). There are 5 parts to the article and helps with understanding some of the concepts of token generation, reissuing tokens, enabling CORS, and using OAuth2.

Comment: in above link how do i customerize below function with my own function to validate user   **public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

            return user;
        }**

Comment: I would do anything that you want customized inside of this FindUser function. This function finds the user in the database and returns it to the calling class, the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider. You could potentially write another function and call that instead.